# Handling dynamic webservices

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, gson

i want to know that is it possible to consume a `WebService` which generate data dynamically based on dynamic fields and the application supports it's changes during parsing? it's not clear to me that how can i use a webservice which, a field might be added later, so the parser for json in older app version would be no longer applicable and it will throw exceptions.what is the best practices for handling dynamic webservices and migrating to new changes in Android? now i'm using `Gson` for parsing a `json` requests with predefined classes , so everythings would be clear to parser and later i use that class. any advice,tutorial or samples for dynamic parsing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to include a version attribute in the JSON message. You can then check the version before parsing the message.

I have worked on applications in the past where we had converters that could convert from

- version 1 -> version 2
- version 2 -> version 3
- version 3 -> version 4

That way, in your application, you can always code against the latest entity (ie version 4). If a version 1 message arrives, it is passed through the 3 converters and enters the application as a version 4 message. If a version 2 message arrives, it only goes through two converters.

Note, you probably won't require a new entity class for every version. Mostly, you will be adding fields over the different versions. In this case the fields can be null for older versions which you can code against with simple null checks.

You may find that you need a set of converters for inbound requests and outbound responses. On the way in, you convert old versions to the latest. On the way out, you convert the latest response to the client's request version.